# Insert Data into MSSQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, insert-into

Hello there am trying to insert data into MSSQL using PHP. I have tried many times to figure out what the problem might be but i seem not to find it. Is there something am not getting right or missing?

```
 <?php
//pull form fields into php variables
$no = $_POST['no'];
$name= $_POST['name'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$leave = $_POST['leave'];
$days= $_POST['days'];
$empno= $_POST['empno'];

//connect to sql
$dbc = mssql_connect('Server-PC','user','password','database')or die('Error connecting to
      the   SQL Server database.');

 // Input into staff database
  $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.[CAGD$Leave Plan] ([No_],[Employee No_],[Employee Name],
 [Leave Name],   [Start Date],[Leave Days],Satus) VALUES   
('$no','$name','$leave','$date','days','empno')";
$r esult = mssql_query($query,$dbc)or die('Error querying MSSQL database');

//close to sql
mssql_close($dbc);

echo $name . 'Your submission has been received<br />';
echo 'If you need change this request please contact your HR Manager<br />';
echo 'Thank you <br />';
echo 'HR Manager';
?>
```

I get this error message:
    Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Invalid object name 'dbo.CAGD Plan'.
    (severity 16) in C:\xampp\htdocs\CAGD\leave_request.php on line 110

```
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in C:\xampp\htdocs  
\CAGD\leave_request.php on line 110
Error querying MSSQL database
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: YES 
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Invalid object name 'dbo.CAGD Plan'. (severity 16) in C:\xampp\htdocs\CAGD\leave_request.php on line 110

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\CAGD\leave_request.php on line 110
Error querying MSSQL database

Comment: Your variable is $leave, not $Leave, so if you're going for something like CAGD4 Plan, change your variable to lowercase.PHP is case sensitive.

Comment: If you can avoid putting spaces in fieldnames, you really should. Yes, you can get around it, but its so ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQLSRV Driver instead of MSSQL Driver and then try this

```
<?php 
$serverName = "serverName";
$options = array(  "UID" => "sa",  "PWD" => "Password",  "Database" => "DBname");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);

if( $conn === false )
     {
     echo "Could not connect.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
     }

$no = $_POST['no'];
$name= $_POST['name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Test
        (No_,FirstName)
        VALUES(?, ?)";
$params1 = array($no,$name);                       
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,$params1);

sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

This is more useful, and you can learn more here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626305(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

First Specify your database Connection...

```
mssql_connect('Server-PC','user','password','database')
like -> "localhost","root","XXXX", "DBNAME"
```

then query like

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME  (id,name) VALUES   
('$id','$name')";
$result = mssql_query($query,$dbc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it seems to me that you have 7 fields in the table but only 6 values submitted - you are missing the value for the first column, `[No_]`.
Besides, the last column `satus` (i suppose it should be 'status') does not have de `[]` delimiters.
The error returned tells you that the name of the table is wrong.
And yes variable names are case sensitive in PHP, it should be $leave - best to exit the string and concatenate - something like `"bla bla".$leave."anything here with spaces or not"` .

Answer (score 0):

Is this supposed to be a variable?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.[CAGD$Leave Plan] ([No_],[Employee No
                               ^^^^^^
```

If so, then it's apparently undefined in your code, and the generated query string will contain `dbo.[CAGD Plan]`, and not whatever value was supposed to be in that variable. If the `$` is literally in your table name, then it should be `CAGD\$Leave`, so that `$Leave` isn't treated as a variable.

Comment: dbo.[CAGD$Leave Plan] is the table name

Comment: then you'll have to escape the `$` so that php doesn't treat `$Leave` as a variable.