# If SQL server is on my computer, how to process a form on a web server?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have Microsoft SQL Server on my computer, and separately, a website. If the action of a form on my site is set to be processed by a php script, how can I use that script to connect to and add data to a database on the SQL Server on my computer?

Thanks!

Comment: you could allow external access to the db server, i cant say i know how. but i think the best solution is to use a db on the server the site is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need the [SQL PHP Drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) then you would need to determine your [connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479763/how-to-get-the-connection-string-from-a-database).  Then you would need to write the php code to insert [into your database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651788/insert-data-into-mssql-db-using-php) (Last Answer).

You also need to [create a table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) with the corresponding schema to hold your data.  This is a very broad question hopefully this puts you on the right track.

Comment: @bst-for-life You may also want to look at some of the video tutorial on youtube that will help you along https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72XCFF4YiOw